# Are OpenSSL byte sequences in little endian or big endian order?

Tags: openssl, endianness, dsa

I'm trying to use openssl dsa implementation, but I'm very confused with the following details:

- Option '-text' of the command `openssl dsa ....`: the hexadecimal numbers in the output, am I correct to assume that those are the bytes, and thus they are in little-Endian order?
- Functions BN_bn2hex and BN_hex2bn, what Endianess they use?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OpenSSL treats all series of bytes (`unsigned char` arrays) as big endian.

The functions `BN_bn2hex` and `BN_hex2bn` are for converting to and from a printable format.  Printable formats are always in natural reading order, which is big endian.

For non-printable format conversions like [bn2bin](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_bn2bin.html), the documentation explicitly states that the conversion is big endian.  But like I said before, the convention in OpenSSL is big endian for all series of bytes.

Comment: @indiv Does this mean I have to do byte swapping for any data that should be passed to OpenSSL API if the code is running on a little endian machine?

Comment: @user3342339:  No.  Only sequence of bytes (typically `unsigned char[]` or `unsigned char *`) that represent numbers are interpreted as big endian.  API functions that accept primitive types like `int` or `long` are host format, as you'd expect.